# How can I solve this problem with latex table?

Tags: tables

I want to make a table like this:

[image]

So I tried with this Latex code:

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|}
        \hline \multirow{2}{3cm}{Filter Type} & 
         \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Ideal impulse response $h_D(n)$} \\
         \cline{2-2} & $h_D(n), \; n\neq 0$ & $h_D(0)$ \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

But I get this table instead:

[image]

I don't know how to fix my problem, so I appreciate if someone could help me.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Write `\cline{2-3}` instead of `\cline{2-2}`.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know it was so simple, maybe I should get more information about de \cline command. Thank you so much!

Comment: Also replace both the `c` columns with `>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2.5cm}` columns in order to have space too (length 2.5 cm is just a guess... test it)

Comment: You're welcome! The syntax is `\cline{StartColumn-EndColumn}`.

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! In general it is better post a complete minimal document that we can compile, rather than a code snippet, cf. [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A minimal modification to your code to get the vertical placing of "Filter Type" and the requested rule is:

[image: First sample]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|}
    \hline Filter Type
    & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Ideal impulse response $h_D(n)$} \\
    \cline{2-3} & $h_D(n), \; n\neq 0$ & $h_D(0)$ \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

However, you should consider whether you need all these vertical rules.  I guess this is just heading material for a table, in which case I would suggest:

[image: Second sample]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{l*{2}{c}}
    \toprule
    Filter Type
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Ideal impulse response $h_D(n)$} \\
    & $n\neq 0$ & $n=0$ \\
    \midrule
    X&$2$&$-1$\\
    Y&$3$&$2$ \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Note that a `table` environment is not necessary, particularly if you want placement at a particular point on the page.  If you need a caption, then the `\captionof` command from the `caption` package can be used.

See the [documentation of the `booktabs` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs/) for more advice on good style for tables.